# How to edit Sharepoint online List cell when another cell is edited

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint list and I need to have each cell in the  "Ops Response" column highlighted green when a person from ops responds to it and red when an entry is put in and no one has responded yet.  I have attached a screen shot of the list

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TimV.jpg)

Comment: Can you explane more this "Ops Response" column? Is this "Ops Response" multi-line-text field? Is this column empty if no one has responded? You can try with column-formatting >https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

Comment: Yes this column is a multi-line-text field.  It is empty once a entrie is created.  I would like the cell in the column to be red when no one has responded and turn green when someone from ops goes into the entry and modifys that cell.

Answer (score 0):

click the dropdown arrow and select "Format This Column"

[image]

In the box that shows at the right, paste in the JSON referenced below.  Click Save.

[image]

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "debugMode": true,
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField != '', 'sp-field-severity--good', if(@currentField == '', 'sp-field-severity--severeWarning', ''))"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Final**

[image]

Comment: How can i get this to work with "append changes to existing text" and "Use enhanced rich text" turned on?.

Comment: Maybe no use enhanced rich text but i would like to keep Append Changes enabled